# Segmentation fault with my Move assignment opertaor overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, move

Note: The bug in the program in this question has been find, and I rearrange the content of the question. If you have similar problem, this post will recommend you to check not only move assignment operator but also destructor.

First, we can see the image to know the data structure of the classes below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc8E4.jpg)

.h

```
class List{
public:
  // Destructor
  ~List();
  // default constructor
  List();
  // move assignment operator
  List& operator=(List&& src);
private:
  Node* lead; ///boundary sentinel: dummy head  
  Node* new_dummy_head();
```

};

.cc

```
// Destroctors
List::~List(){
  Node* cur = lead->next;
  Node* nex = cur->next;
  while(cur->data!=NULL){
    delete cur;
    cur = nex;
    nex = nex->next;
  }
  delete lead;
}

// default constructors (just create a dummy node)
List::List(){
  lead = new_dummy_head();
}

// move assignment operator overloading

List& List::operator=(List&& src){
  // Release any resources *this owns and Reset *this
  // not the point of question, hide it

  // pilfer src
  lead = src.lead;

  // Reset source object
  src.lead = NULL;
  return *this;
}

Node* List::new_dummy_head(){
  Node* ptr = new Node;
  cerr << ptr->data << endl;
  ptr->prev = ptr->next = ptr;
  return ptr;
}
```

main.cc

```
int main()
{
  List beta;
  beta = List();
  return 0;
}
```

and then get

```
segmentation fault
```

Comment: What does the ``Node`` destructor do ?

Comment: You don't have a copy-constructor

Comment: Not related to the problem, but a **public** `// internal enum` is an oxymoron.

Comment: Your loop deletes what `lead` is pointing at. So what do you think that makes `lead->next` be?

Comment: @nefas , Node<E> has a private member pointer, and the destructor of Node has only one line that delete that pointer.

Comment: @StoryTeller , Sorry that I didn't mention that it is a circular bidirected list, and I try `cerr << lead->data` below loop and it works. Also we can see that we can print `bottom` which locate in the bottom of definition of move assginment

Comment: @FrankWang One peculiarity of undefined operations is that they may appear to work. That doesn't mean that they're not broken.

Comment: @FrankWang this pointer is ``next`` ? Could you add the implementation of the destructor in the question ?

Comment: Whenever I have to deal with pointer juggling like this (almost never), I print a lot of pointers at every stage to make sure I'm doing everything I **think** I'm doing and nothing I **think** I'm not.

Comment: @nefas , Thanks for your reminder, I just add some definition at the part of note in the question for your reference.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano, I get the same error output even I comment whole loop in the definition of move assignment operator

Comment: @FrankWang If you haven't figured this out yet (I haven't tried compiling anything here), try asking again with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @KhouriGiordano, I find the bug when I try to rearrange my question according to the post. I will try to not repeat the same mistake when asking question. Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In this Program, destructor of List assume there's a dummy node pointed by `lead`, but we can see that in the definition of move assignment operator

```
  // Reset source object
  src.lead = NULL;
  return *this;
```

it set `lead` of rvalue object NULL, so it will be segmentation fault when destroy move-from object